# ZXing Decoder Online - Submit Error

Tags: java, decoder

I installed the script on my server

Permission in JAVA is 750

MY URL IS - 
http://java.sailorweb.com.br/java/decode.jspx

When I click submit in either the url or image I get an error

```
==================================
HTTP Status 404 - /java/decode
type Status report
message /java/decode
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
===================================
```

What could be wrong?
Because it does not work like the online script
https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Could you please help?

Comment: Obviously, your `<form … action="decode">` lacks *.jspx* extension after *decode* URI. Otherwise, you may want to reconfigure your web server to redirect */java/decode* to */java/decode.aspx* transparently.

Comment: Hello
I made the adjustment by putting the .jspx in the form
Although the original file
Do not contain this modification

Https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Even so, nothing came.
Did not work

Comment: The original code did not have “.jspx” in the form action link, because their server was setup differently than yours (in term of either URL rewriting or file-type handling). It is hard to tell why your server-side script ignores the `u` parameter (as if nothing was submitted) without seeing its code, — consider attaching it to your post unless its 100 % identical to the original one at GitHub.

Comment: Hello good Morning.
My code is 100% identical to the original one on GitHub.

I am making it available as a zip file.

By adding decoder.jspx in the file submit, nothing happens.
The page simply loads again without processing the file or url link.

I really need your help.

Comment: URL is - java.sailorweb.com.br/webapp.rar

Comment: We are back at comment #1 now. If you want to use the original code verbatim (which is totally fine), you must configure your web server to substitute */java/decode* with */java/decode.aspx* behind the scenes.

Comment: Moreover, it appears that *decode.aspx* simply does not contain any program code to process the request. While being unfamiliar with Java and JSP, it is hard to judge which *.jspx* file is responsible for the processing, even if helped by other *.java* files being included. However I am suspecting that URL rewriting may be required here once again, — that is, the web server should route the request to an appropriate *.jspx* file depending on whether the request is (1) simple GET without parameters, (2) GET with “?u=…”, (3) POST.

Comment: By the way, why don't you open an issue on the project's GitHub page and give them feedback about their *zxingorg* source tree lacking installation instructions? Indeed, their [Documentation Site](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/) contains a dead link when it comes to [ZXing zxing.org web app](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/zxingorg/index.html).